# Opentok react native not publishing

Tags: react-native, opentok, tokbox

I'm trying to build an app with [opentok-react-native](https://github.com/opentok/opentok-react-native/) library.

When the app is running, the publisher component becomes a black square and the subscriber component shows my camera video.

In the logs I can see that the stream is created, with a stream ID and apparently is working. But when I go to my [Tokbox account](https://tokbox.com/account/) I can't see any data on my dashboard:
[image: tokbox dashboard]

Here is my current code: https://github.com/victor0402/opentok-demo

The important part is:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {OT, OTPublisher, OTSession, OTSubscriber} from "opentok-react-native";

export default class App extends Component {

  //Publisher token
  token = 'TOKEN HERE';

  //Routed session ID
  session = 'SESSION ID HERE';

  apiKey = 'API KEY';

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      streamProperties: {},
    };

    this.publisherProperties = {
      publishVideo: true,
      publishAudio: true,
      cameraPosition: 'front'
    };

    this.publisherEventHandlers = {
      streamCreated: event => {
        console.log('publisherEventHandlers: streamCreated.... updating state');
        const streamProperties = {
          ...this.state.streamProperties, [event.streamId]: {
            subscribeToAudio: true,
            subscribeToVideo: true,
            style: {
              width: 400,
              height: 300,
            },
          }
        };
        this.setState({streamProperties});
      },
      streamDestroyed: event => {
        console.log('Publisher stream destroyed!', event);
      }
    };

    this.subscriberProperties = {
      subscribeToAudio: true,
      subscribeToVideo: true,
    };

    this.sessionEventHandlers = {
      streamCreated: event => {
        console.log('sessionEventHandlers : streamCreated');
      },

      streamDestroyed: event => {
        console.log('Stream destroyed!!!!!!', event);
      },
    };

    this.subscriberEventHandlers = {
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(`There was an error with the subscriber: ${error}`);
      },
    };
  }

  render() {
    OT.enableLogs(true);

    return (
      <View>
        <OTSession apiKey={this.apiKey} sessionId={this.session} token={this.token}
                   eventHandlers={this.sessionEventHandlers}>

          <OTPublisher
            properties={this.publisherProperties}
            eventHandlers={this.publisherEventHandlers}
            style={{ height: 100, width: 100 }}
          />

          <OTSubscriber
            properties={this.subscriberProperties}
            eventHandlers={this.subscriberEventHandlers}
            style={{height: 100, width: 100}}
            streamProperties={this.state.streamProperties}
          />
        </OTSession>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

So, is there something wrong with my code? 
How can I publish a vídeo and get the results and recordings on my account dashboard?

Comment: Is this happening on ios or android?

Comment: @10101010 On android 5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TokBox Developer Evangelist here.

The usage metrics take about 24 hours to populate in the dashboard which is why you're not seeing them immediately.

I also reviewed the code you shared and it looks like your setting the `streamProperties` object in the `streamCreated` callback for `OTPublisher`. Please note that the `streamCreated` event for the publisher will only fire when your publisher starts to publish. Since you're using the `streamProperties` to set properties for the subscriber, you should be setting this data in the `streamCreated` event callback for `OTSession` because that's dispatched when a new stream (other than your own) is created in a session. Your code would then look something like this:

```
this.sessionEventHandlers = {
  streamCreated: event => {
      const streamProperties = {
      ...this.state.streamProperties, [event.streamId]: {
        subscribeToAudio: true,
        subscribeToVideo: true,
        style: {
          width: 400,
          height: 300,
        },
      }
    };
    this.setState({streamProperties});
  },
};
```

Lastly to check and see if everything is working correctly, I recommend using the [OpenTok Playground Tool](https://tokbox.com/developer/tools/playground_doc/) and connect with the same sessionId as the one in your React Native application.

Comment: I thought that would be some problem with my code. Good to know about the playground tool. Thank you very much @manik.

Comment: Happy to help @Victor!

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using updated vrsion

```
"opentok-react-native": "^0.17.2"
```